# How to show the task definition template content when running `terraform plan` or `apply`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-template-file

I deploy the ecs service via terraform, and define the task definition via `template_file` data source.

```
data "template_file" "task_definition" {
  template = "${file("${"${path.module}/task-definition.json"}")}"

  vars {
    region         = "${var.region}"
    consul_address = "${aws_instance.consul.private_ip}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family                = "service"
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.task_definition.rendered}"

  volume {
    name      = "service-storage"
    host_path = "/ecs/service-storage"
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-west-2a, us-west-2b]"
  }
}
```

But when I run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` after change the task definition template, it only shows me

```
  task_definition: "arn:aws:ecs:xxxx:xxxx:task-definition/xxxx-task-definition:15" => "${aws_ecs_task_definition.service.arn}"
```

But doesn't show me the final content of the task definition.

So are there any ways to show the latest task definition (**with all vars are replaces with real value**)?

#### Updates

Seems this problem has been reported by someone already.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-template/issues/4

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/8669